# why is declaring inside for loop works but declaring outside for loop as global variable won't work

Tags: java

I am not sure why I need to declare count and correct inside the first for loop here. I originally declared them as global variable but I am modifying them inside for loop. If I don't declare them inside for loop they remain the same value I think. My logic is the value gets changed inside for loop. Am I approaching this thoughts wrong?

```
    public static double[] gradeAllStudents(char[][] response, char[] soln) {
//      int count = 0;
        int len = soln.length;
//      int correct = 0;
        double[] result = new double[response.length];
        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            double correct = 0;
//          System.out.println(response[i].length);
            for(int j = 0; j < response[i].length; j++) {
                if (soln[j] == response[i][j]) {
                     correct= correct+1;
                }

                count ++;
            }
//          System.out.println(correct);
            result[index] = 100*(correct)/(response[i].length);
            index++;
            if(count != len) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong exam");
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you declare it outside the loop, you have to make sure to reset it to `0` in the loop, otherwise it'll retain the value from the previous iteration, and it will throw your "wrong exam" exception

Comment: @thatotherguy that is the point though, I'm not trying to reset it to 0. I am changing the values in for loop with each iteration

Comment: @thatotherguy i just understood what you meant, thank you

Comment: Declaring it outside the loop doesn't make it 'global'. There are no global variables in Java, and if there were this wouldn't be one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that i got your problem

but

you can declare variable outside for loop and changing them inside.

in your example the code will look like this

```
    public static double[] gradeAllStudents(char[][] response, char[] soln) {
        int count;
        int len = soln.length;
        int correct;
        double[] result = new double[response.length];
        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            count = 0; // restart value of count
            correct = 0; // restart value of correct
//          System.out.println(response[i].length);
            for(int j = 0; j < response[i].length; j++) {
                if (soln[j] == response[i][j]) {
                     correct= correct+1;
                }

                count ++;
            }
//          System.out.println(correct);
            result[index] = 100*(correct)/(response[i].length);
            index++;
            if(count != len) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong exam");
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

PS : you can improve your code

this still simple but better

```
public static double[] gradeAllStudents(char[][] response, char[] soln) {
    final int len = soln.length; // this is a constant
    int correct;
    double[] result = new double[response.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        correct = 0;
        if (len != response[i].length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong exam");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < response[i].length; j++) {
            if (soln[j] == response[i][j]) {
                correct ++;
            }
        }
        result[i] = (double)(100 * correct) / response[i].length; // casting after math operation improve the performance
    }
    return result;
}
```

**finally welcome to java** :D

Comment: hi! thank you. your solution makes sense to me. But I'm still not hundred percent sure why declaring count and correct inside for loop works. I thought i need to declare them inside for loop because otherwise at every iteration they will start from zero....so confused right now

Comment: all variables inside for loop will removed after every iteration but other variable (variable outside loop, class attributes, static variable etc...) will stay and you can use them inside iteration.